# upgrade python from 2.4 to 2.6 in plone

Tags: python, plone

I am trying to upgrade my plone version from 3.3.5 to 4.0. For this I went to this site: [updating plone](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/upgrade-guide/version/upgrading-plone-3-x-to-4.0/buildout-3-4). But I got stuck in the first point. In plone 3, I have python version of 2.4. But for plone 4.x I will need python 2.6. How do I upgrade my python version? In my buildout.cfg I have:

```
$extra-paths = ${instance:zope2-location}/lib/py
```

and in my versions.cfg, I have external dependencies and in that section I have `python-openid = 2.2.4`.

Answer (score 2):

To upgrade python it really depends on the underlying OS (operating system). If a OS specific upgrade fails, download python from http://www.python.org/download/ and install it from source.

You might have to upgrade some of the paths in your buildout.cfg

Answer (score 1):

You don't upgrade Python, you install a new version in parallell.